# Return Column and Row name of largest correlation pair, correlation martix in R

Tags: r

I'm trying to return the maximum value and its column, row in a correlation matrix in R using this line of code.
The correlation matrix is called cor_mat and I don't want to include the values that = 1 because those are variables' correlation with themselves.

This is my matrix

```
cor_mat.data <- c(1.00, 0.70,0.31,0.11,0.70,1.00,0.19,0.07,0.31,0.19,1.00,0.45,0.11,0.07,0.45,1.00)

cor_mat <- matrix(cor_mat.data, nrow=4,ncol=4,byrow=TRUE)
```

and this is what I've been trying:

```
which(abs(cor_mat) == max(cor_mat) && abs(cor_mat) != 1, arr.ind = TRUE)
```

Any advice is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have to make sure that we keep correlations that are 1 but aren’t located in the diagonal where the correlations of variables with themselves are located.

With `upper.tri` we can filter all values of the diagonal and the lower triangle (because values in upper and lower triangle are the same by definition).

```r
cor_mat.data <- c(1.00, 0.70,0.31,0.11,0.70,1.00,0.19,0.07,0.31,0.19,1.00,0.45,0.11,0.07,0.45,1.00)
cor_mat <- matrix(cor_mat.data, nrow=4,ncol=4,byrow=TRUE)

MaxVal <- max(abs(cor_mat[upper.tri(cor_mat)]))
which(abs(cor_mat) == MaxVal, arr.ind = TRUE)
#>      row col
#> [1,]   2   1
#> [2,]   1   2
```

<sup>Created on 2021-10-14 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Answer (score 2):

Are you looking for this?

maximum value in matrix:

```
max(abs(cor_mat[upper.tri(cor_mat)]))
```

index/indices of maximum(s):

```
which(cor_mat == max(abs(cor_mat[upper.tri(cor_mat)])), arr.ind = T)
```

Comment: ah yes, thanks! I've updated using your answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
max(sort(cor_mat[cor_mat != 1]))
```

Which gives us:

```
[1] 0.7
```

Comment: Sorry, I just updated the question. I wanted the line to return the max value and then the column and row name for the value if possible? But thank you!

Comment: This would exclude all correlations of 1 and not only those correlations of a variable with itself (ie the diagonal)?